# Can destruction order be controlled across dynamic libraries?

Tags: c++, linux

I am encountering an issue where my library is crashing due to executable that loads me calling my function after main exits. I'm wondering - can I control the lifecycle of my globals to not be destroyed until (and if) my library gets unloaded? I understand what I'm asking.

Basically, the executable looks something like this (roughly):

```
struct MyLibController
{
    void *libhandle;
    void (*function)() myLibFunction;
    ~MyLibController()
    {
        myLibFunction();      // Call to my library's exported function
        dlclose(libhandle);
    }

};
std::shared_ptr<MyLibController> globalPtr;

int main(int argc, const char **argv)
{
    globalPtr = std::make_shared<MyLibController>();
    // initializing globalPtr to dlopen my library, map function ptrs, etc.
    // do some work with my library
    return 0;
}
```

I have absolutely no control over the code in this executable.

My library code look something like this:

```
SomeType globalObject;

// Exported function via c interface in my library
void myLibFunction()
{
    // crash occurs globalObject is used after executable's main function exits 
    globalObject.someFunction();
    // do some work
}
```

I have a lot of control over the library code - but this is a simple example. The Sometype globalObject is very necessary (suppose that it's a mutex, used to sync myLibFunction and a bunch of others).

I'd like to ensure that my globalObject is valid even after executable's main function exits. Is this possible? If so, how?

P.S. I am aware that I can dynamically allocate the globalObject and leak it, which resolves the crash. It feels wrong though, and I don't want to sign off on it.

Comment: Which platform is this intended to run on? On windows you could use `DllMain()`, and filter for `DLL_PROCESS_DETACH`

Comment: Using `__attribute__((constructor))` and `__attribute__((destructor))` allows you to specify a priority, but I think that's still within a SO. I'm pretty sure library destruction order is forced to be the opposite of load order ... though perhaps manually incrementing the refcount would change that?

Comment: @o11c - please consider making your comment an answer so that I could mark it as such, I think this is exactly what's needed. I can dynamically allocate globalObject through __attribute__((constructor)), and destroy it through __attribute__((destructor)), thereby allowing my object's life span to match that of library load state. I still have to test, but I think this is it.

Comment: @Kaa I *haven't* tested it, thus I won't answer ... but you can answer your own question based on your tests.

Comment: @o11c - I just tested your solution and it works perfectly. Up to you - I'll wait a few hours - and if you don't post it - I will go ahead and do it. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@o11c's comment provided a working solution:

> Using **attribute**((constructor)) and **attribute**((destructor))
>   allows you to specify a priority

In other words, I can have the control over lifecycle of my variables despite binary's main function exiting (I just have to dynamically allocate them and free them).

Answer (score 3):

You can register for a callback when the `main()` returns using `std::atexit()`: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/atexit

For example, when your library is loaded, use `atexit()` to register, then when that callback fires, set a flag for yourself that you check before trying to do anything else.  If the flag is set, ignore any other actions from the caller, because the program is shutting down.

Comment: This may work... so I would use std::atexit() to set a flag indicating that global destruction has begun (in a sense), and force myself to no longer rely on the globalObject in my library. Ideally I'd like to track my library's load state - and only destroy globals when library is unloaded, but this may work. I will test this and other suggestions to see if they solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to make your global object a reference counted singleton of some sort.  Then update your interface to instantiate an object from your loaded library.  This object can then grab a reference to the global object during construction, and thus only releases it after it has been destroyed.  The global variable itself would also merely have a reference, thus during the dlclose() process the global reference would be released, but your object would still have a reference until it is destroyed.

Comment: At first your answer seemed naive, but I think this can work too.
I can my make my global like this:
std::shared_ptr<SomeType> globalObject = std::make_shared.....;

Then have this: shared_ptr<SomeType> getObj(){ static std::shared_ptr<SomeType> obj = globalObject; return obj;}

In my function I would then do:
void myLibFunction()
{
    auto obj = getObj();
    ....
}
It might actually work. I can't use a singleton because I don't know when my library is unloaded, so thereby can't release it.

Comment: In your scenario, do you need to support having `dlclose() ` called in your library? Or is it only ever loaded once and then stays in place until the program exits?

Comment: I need to support both scenarios, whether my library is loaded explicitly or implicitly. I just tested o11c's solution (in question comments) - and it works perfectly with very minimal infrastructure changes to my code. Thank you.